# Rotating a google map container but not the map itself

Tags: css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was just wondering if there was a more efficient approach to doing the [this](http://s23.postimage.org/gxn7ku597/Capture.png) with a Google map rather then layering this beneath a rotated div, so that its almost a cutout effect. for example you should surely be able to rotate the google map container and leave the actual map un-rotated..

I have been researching but not finding much...

Okay so after experimenting for a while I've gotten [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/vHNsb/3/) far(cant get google map to display in jsfiddle)

Heres the code:

CSS:

```
#map{
height:200px;
width:200px;
/* FF Chrome Opera etc */
-moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
-o-transform:rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476); /* IE6,IE7 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)"; /* IE8 */
zoom:1;

/* IE */
}
#map > div > div > div > div > div{
    -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476); /* IE6,IE7 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)"; /* IE8 */
zoom:1;
}
```

JS:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 5,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
  disableDefaultUI: true,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="map" style="width:200px; height:200px;"></div>
```

I have gotten it to work entirely now... 1 problem left... IE7 and IE8 :/.. Any advice on rotation in them?

Any Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you rotate the wrapper and give it `overflow: hidden` then rotate the map the same way but in the opposite direction to bring it back horizontal?

Comment: look at the update, should give you a good idea of what i am trying to achieve.. :)

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle with a working Google Map.  Have fun:  http://jsfiddle.net/gdVXG/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 212px;  // Use pythagoras' theorem to get these from required height/width
    height: 212px; // Sqrt(212 x 212 x 2) = 300 approximately
    background: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#map {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    top: -45px; // line it back up (not sure why it isn't: rotation weird?)
    left: -45px;
    background: #fdd url(http://www.somersethouse.org.uk/images/mi/visit/map.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vHNsb/2/)

Comment: It would be nice if your jsFiddle showed a live map instead of a background image... just to be sure.

Comment: I have no clue how to do that. I've never used the API. It wouldn't be hard for you to implement it yourself and test it.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly.. just not in IE7 or 8 and also it cuts out the terms of use and Google logo(Google wont like that), see updated example.. please help with IE7 an IE8

Comment: It's just not gonna happen in older browsers.